# Invoke class method php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

this is my example:

```
class test {

function tester(){
    do something;
}
}
```

I need to check in ajax if the button is clicked:

```
echo "<button name=\"updateList\" type=\"button\">&#8635; Update the List</button>";
```

if is, using ajax i need to **invoke tester method**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({url:"index.php",
          type: "post",
          data: {action: 'updateList'}
          }); 
      });   
    });
```

i need some hints or help how to this, i want to do this becouse i don't want my page to refresh after button is clicked.

Comment: I guess you should develop your own router logic. For instance, here, `controller name` will be test and `action name` tester. It's depends on your needs and your app architecture.

Answer (score 0):

```
//index.php

if(isset($_POST['action']&&$_POST['action']=='updatelist'){
    $test = new Test();
    $test->tester();
}
```